# Name generator using Generics

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

I am trying to generate a Name based on type of an object. In my system, I have,

```
class Employee {}

Class ContractEmp:Employee{}

class Manager:Employee{}
```

I am trying to generate name which looks like ContractEmp1 Where 1 will come from incrementer. I am trying to use Generics.

Any Help

Thank you,

Comment: Why are you trying to use generics for something like this?

Comment: Generics because, this piece of code is same for all the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an extension method you could do something like this:

```
public static class NameExtension
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> counters = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public static string MakeUpName<T>(this T @object)
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        if ( ! counters.ContainsKey(t.FullName))
            counters[t.FullName] = 0;

        return t.Name + counters[t.FullName]++;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[TestFixture]
class NameTest
{
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new NameTest().MakeUpName());
        Console.WriteLine(new NameTest().MakeUpName());
        Console.WriteLine(new NameTest().MakeUpName());
        Console.WriteLine(new NameTest().MakeUpName());
    }
}
```

Output:

> NameTest0
>   NameTest1
>   NameTest2
>   NameTest3

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the code. Code I have right now, which is similar to the one you wrote. But in multi session application, when I create another object(say Nametest), strings are created from previous sessions data. But I will check you code. Thanks again

Comment: Then you'll need to make it non-static (and don't use extension method) and create a new name generator per session.

Comment: Also, you should share the code you've already written in your question and explain what you're having problems with.

Comment: It worked for me. I was previously using statics. Thank you you Svish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private static int in the Employee class which gets incremented on each constructor call. Combining this number with the typeof(this).Name value you can generate the names as described. Do note that the counter will count for all Employee extending classes so if you want an consecutive list of numbers for each Employee extending class, a specific counter should be implemented for every extending class. Also, the counters will be set to zero each time the application restarts.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Class ContractEmp:Employee{
    private static int counter = 1;
    private String name = "";

    public ContractEmp() {
      name = typeof(this).Name + counter++;
    }
}
```

Something like this should work!